# How to use Box Pierce Test in python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

In statsmodels I can only find the Ljung-Box test, which is apparently different to the Box-Pierce test. How would I use the box pierce test in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

statsmodels `ljung_box` has a keyword option `boxpierce`. If this is set to true, then it returns box-pierce test results in addition to those for ljung-box

`https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.acorr_ljungbox.html